# Best search bibliographic database

Tags: citations, reference-managers

I was evaluating Jabref and found it has a bibliography web search tool.
You can choose among:

```
ACM Portal   
Arxiv   
Crossref   
DBLP   
DOAJ   
GVK   
Google Scholar   
IEEEXplore     
Inspire   
MathSciNet   
Springer
```

Which one offers more or better results when looking for a given scientific or technologic article?

Comment: "*Which one offers more or better results when looking for a given scientific or technologic article?*" Surely this depends on the article. For example, if I were looking for an article that happens to involve [Stone-Čech compactifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification), I would not expect to find anything useful from IEEEXplore, and I would probably start with MathSciNet.